# TypeScript: Infer generic type from calling class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `Base` class that my `Parent` class extends from.  In the `Base` class, I have a `static create` that handles creating an instance of my classes.  I would like to add type safety to this, so I made it a generic function.  [Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQPRegFQHkARAgLmgEkYAXACwQCckxoB3MAT2moHtoBLAHYAzRt3rcOAB2Y0JwMCBBCA5tFCQIAfnSYI1MNX7B1TQwgA8eAHwAKACaGwW8ngCUrlLsyZgPQfrQTH4M9tAAvNCCCKzQtgQARgBWCMDUAHQqCNQACgw8vNTSCATCtnT8EG5utm4A3N4%200Ikpaema-CqCtsE8oQA00I4G9Y0%20TNQArgyCQal99g0%20AL6oq6gaUNA5YEyC1NAIAB7UCIL2MPAQSGg%20gmAAtkiRAOQvDes4%20LSVAnJIUiYogYTDC7C4PGE6kUykEagqMCedB49kGCUmBzoSCKMjmUxmCDCvwARJNBABrQQ8ViCYkbfyBXqhCLbXZnDLAMynWqoL6EEjkChsHiTEBhBiGegMKIFaC0MAAN2xfCkmlZewOkHESCy0QYxkkuKlzHOAhEYn4BwgPCetGp9ICByZ9gA6n1yTBIjsNelOQhzBZvey7KM-AEeCAEOkQDwVD15qF0vcnoNnW6GB6k48EG4gA) and code:

```
class Base {
    // TODO: Is there a way to infer the type as the calling class?
    static create<T>(data?: T): T {
        const record = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(this))();
        Object.assign(record, data);
        return record;
    }
}

class Parent extends Base {
    name = '';
}

// This is the preferred way of calling this method, but the type returned is "unknown"
const record = Parent.create()
// TODO: I would rather not have to pass Parent as the type here and infer it somehow
const recordWorks = Parent.create<Parent>();
console.log(record.name, recordWorks.name)
```

The problem I'm having is in order to invoke it from the child class, I have to pass the child class as the type (like with `recordWorks`, which is a little redundant).  Ideally I could call the create function, and it'd infer the type from the class calling it.  Is something like this possible?

I realize I can have my `create` method look more like the [docs example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) and pass my class as an argument, but this seems a little goofy to me.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W46M7N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Note: The object returned is not of class `Parent`  with what @jcalz has shown.  But then again, neither was yours.. :) eg..  `console.log(record instanceof Parent)  // = false`

Comment: @Keith I didn't change the implementation from the question as I thought the point was the typings; probably the OP should change the implementation to do the right thing instead with just `new this()` (updated code [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaDypw)), assuming that's the intent.

Comment: @jcalz  Yeah, I updated my comment with that fact.  Currently as the OP has it, having `class Parent` has become pointless,..

Comment: Thank you both for pointing that out!  And thanks @jcalz for the updated Fiddle, much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, updated snippet looks the biz.. :)

Comment: Now if only there was a way of getting this working with `new` instead, haha